# UIPickerView as inputView for UITextView swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, uipickerview

I have used UIPickerView as inputView for UITextView.
The `selectRow:` function doesn't select properly for alternate time

Here is the code

```
func textViewDidBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
    let inputView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0,y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 240))
    let codePicker = UIPickerView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.bounds.width, height: 240))
    codePicker.tag = 2

    if codePicker.dataSource == nil {
        codePicker.dataSource = self
    }
    if codePicker.delegate == nil {
        codePicker.delegate = self
    }

    codePicker.showsSelectionIndicator = true
    print("selectedBankRow: \(selectedRow)")
    codePicker.selectRow(selectedRow, inComponent: 0, animated: true)
    inputView.addSubview(codePicker)
    textView.inputView = inputView
    return
}
```

The print statement print correct row but the `selectRow:` function selects the previous to the previous value which was selected, what could be the error? Even the status bar goes black each alternate time only for this UITextView interaction.

Comment: Why you are creating picker view every time ? Create global object instead and add as inputview in view did load method

Comment: Why use a `UITextView` instead of a `UITextField`? Most likely you are only selecting a single line of text from the picker so no needs for the multiline text view.

Comment: @rmaddy because I need to show multiple numbers of lines, with `UITextField` I can't achieve that.

Comment: Thanks @PrashantTukadiya your suggestion solved the `selectRow:` function malfunctioning problem. But the status bar problem is still there.

Comment: I manage to fix the `statusBar` issue by implementing this `IQKeyboardManager.sharedManager().canAdjustAdditionalSafeAreaInsets = true`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't create `UIPickerView` every time

Create Global Object

```
var codePicker = UIPickerView()
```

and in viewDidLoad Method

add following code

```
let inputView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0,y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 240))
codePicker = UIPickerView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.bounds.width, height: 240))
codePicker.tag = 2
codePicker.dataSource = self
codePicker.delegate = self

codePicker.showsSelectionIndicator = true
print("selectedBankRow: \(selectedRow)")
codePicker.selectRow(selectedRow, inComponent: 0, animated: true)
inputView.addSubview(codePicker)
textView.inputView = inputView
```

as you solved Status bar issue  with

```
IQKeyboardManager.sharedManager().canAdjustAdditionalSafeAreaInsets = true
```

Hope it is helpful